# Adobe Flash CS6 AIR for iOS launch image

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I have developed an app with AIR for iOS - AS3. I tried to upload a new release, but I have the following error:

*iPhone 5 Optimization Requirement - Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5. As of May 1, all new iPhone apps and app updates submitted must support the 4-inch display on iPhone 5. All apps must include a launch image of the appropriate size. Learn more about iPhone 5 support by reviewing the iOS Human Interface Guidelines.*

I've been reviewing all Apple documentation but I don't know what are they talking about.

As I can understand, this launch image is the image that is showed while the app is loading the content (in the preloader screen). Is this true?

Or is another thing? in XCode I saw that you can add this launch image in a menu, but in Flash not.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I found that in the answers here an important step wasn't mentioned so it wasn't working for me. But since trying a little bit it's no problem at all: If you are using the Flash Professional IDE you just have to add the desired images to your root application folder as mentioned above. 
But as not mentioned in the answers here you have to add those files to your

```
'Included files'-Section
```

in the

```
'Preferences for AIR for iOS'-Panel.
```

Just click on the '+'- button to navigate to the images to add them there too. They will automatically be included in compilation process and you are done. Your application will display the desired launch images and if you add a default-h568@2x.png image your application will automatically display full-screen even on retina 4-inch devices.

Answer (score 4):

The launch images must be stored directly under src.  There must be multiple launch files there for different devices:

1. iphone 3GS should be named Default.png and should be 320x480
2. iphone 4 should be named Default@2x.png and should be 640x960
3. iphone 5 should be named Default-568h@2x.png and should be 640x1136

Your code does not need to reference these images.  They are used by the OS as it starts your app.

If you need your launch images to be globalized, the naming is more complicated.

See the following for more complete documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW12

Comment: I just tried this answer and it worked for me. Didn't have to change anything else.  Also - make sure you add at least one 4-inch retina screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is attach image (PNG) with name "Default-568h@2x.png" and size 640x1136, it will set up IPhone 5 resolution. I have just checked it and it work's fine.

Comment: Many thanks! but where I have to attach the image? I cannot find where in iTunesConnect, I can only attach screenshots, not launch images.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach the image("Default-568h@2x.png") to the root level with your APP-NAME-app.xml.

Just like this:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23443325/pic/2013-05-27_170737.png

You will see the lanuch image when you start the app on your iOS device.

I hope it will be helpful to you.
Good Luck :)

Additional:
Finally, I upload the *.ipa successfully and no reject notification.
You can update the AIR SDK to the newst version and publish.