# AS3 Air uploading .ipa IOS using Application Loader ERROR ITMS-9000;

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, application-loader

I am using the Flash CC IDE and AS3 with air to create my IOS app. I am trying to upload it via the Application Loader and I am getting these errors in the  image below. I have no idea on how to fix this. It says something about some -568h image THAT SHOULD BE FOLLOWING the `<basename>` etc.. and I have no idea what this means.

[image]

Comment: Add splash image which name like Default-568h@2x~iphone.png(size 640x1136), it is for iPhone 5. missing <gap:splash src="Default-568h@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136" />

Comment: Do I need to "include" that via the flash IDE or will it just "upload" if the image is there and I put that code in the xml?

Comment: copy Default-568h@2x.png in splash folder and build again.

Comment: I am using Flash CC. Where is the "splash" folder?

Comment: ahhh :) Where do I put this line in the xml? <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="1136" src="AppIconsForPublish/Default-568h@2x.png" width="640"/>

Comment: I am using Flash IDE and Xml. Does this apply? What is  phonegap?

Comment: See http://phonegap.com/

Comment: ok so will this help me with exporting a FLASH IOS AIR APP?

Comment: I am thinking PhoneGap is some sort of program. I am looking for AS3 code exporing an .apk through the Flash IDE.

Comment: it is wrapper inside ios webview.

Comment: I think we are talking about 2 different things. I am talking about FLASH AS3 AND XML, not a web app.

Comment: Ok...bcoz your question is tagged in Phonegap section.

Comment: strange. Ok that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here:
[Adobe Flash CS6 AIR for iOS launch image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16605421/adobe-flash-cs6-air-for-ios-launch-image)

When using the FLASH IDE you simply have to add the image to the root folder.

Also you must use latest Adobe AIR from 15.0.0.302 labs.adobe.com or released if it version greater. –   - Thank you Anton Vladimirovich Oct 12 at 20:58

Comment: Also you must use latest Adobe AIR from 15.0.0.302 labs.adobe.com or released if it version greater.